# Javascript bootstrap modal calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is like below:

```
function OnApply(runFunc) {
    $("#myCfmModal").modal('show');    
    $("#myCfmModal").find("#myCfmModalText").html("Apply change now?"); 
    $("#myCfmModal").find("#myCfmModalHeader").css("background","#cccccc");
    $("#myCfmModal").one('click', '#okbtn', runFunc);            
}

function cool() {
    alert("cool!");
}
```

I have a problem running the code above. I call the `OnApply(cool())` as below:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="OnApply(cool())">Apply</button>
```

`OnApply(cool())` will show a modal box and run a function `cool()`. What I want to do is to run function `cool()` when I click the OK button in the modal box. However the `cool()` function will always run first before I click the OK button. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: How are you calling `OnApply()`?

Comment: I call it when I click a button

Comment: Ok, but do you pass the reference of the function, `OnApply(cool)`, or the returned value of the function, `OnApply(cool())`? The latter will cause this issue, as you should be using the first method.

Comment: Check this plugin : https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal .. you can stack modals in it too .. and you achieve what you are trying to do easily ..

Comment: Rory McCrossan, what do you mean by pass reference of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are passing the *result* of the `cool()` function to `OnApply()` - you instead need to pass the reference to the function by removing the trailing brackets. Try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="OnApply(cool)">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `runFunc` using "`click`" JavaScript event.

Try this.

```
function OnApply(runFunc)
{
  $("#myCfmModal").modal('show');    
  $("#myCfmModal").find("#myCfmModalText").html("Apply change now?");
  $("#myCfmModal").find("#myCfmModalHeader").css("background","#cccccc");
  $("#myCfmModal").find('#okbtn').click(functions(){
    runFunc();
  });
}
function cool()
{
  alert("cool!");
}
```